# change value during animation (SKAction) iOS

Tags: ios, animation, sprite-kit, skaction

I have the animation like below.

sit animation:

```
SKTexture *sit1 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"sit_1_blur.png"];
SKTexture *sit2 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"sit_2_blur.png"];
SKTexture *sit3 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"sit_3_blur.png"];
SKTexture *sit4 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"sit_4_blur.png"];
SKTexture *sit5 = [SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"sit_5_blur.png"];

NSArray *sitPng   = @[sit1,sit2,sit3];
NSArray *drinkPng = @[sit3,sit4,sit5];

sitAnimation   = [SKAction animateWithTextures:sitPng timePerFrame:0.2];
drinkAnimation = [SKAction animateWithTextures:drinkPng timePerFrame:1];


-(void) takeSit{
    [self runAction:sitAnimation completion:^{
        [self startDrink];
    }];
}
```

How can I change value every second during `startDrink` animation? Like so:

```
someValue +=0.2;
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What is someValue? What type? Does it affect the appearance of an object? What is sitAnimation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have this inside your startDrink Animation (I am assuming startDrink is another action defined somewhere),

```
+ (SKAction *)customActionWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)seconds actionBlock:(void (^)(SKNode *node, CGFloat elapsedTime))block;
```

measure the the time passed and update someValue +=0.2; accordingly.

Hope this helps.